# Parsing JSON String From Factual API

Tags: jquery, json

Like the title says, I am using Factual API to return some places near a geolocation and am having issues parsing the data with jQuery. An example of the full json string I have returned is similar to this:

```
"{
\"version\": 3,
\"status\": \"ok\",
\"response\": {
    \"data\": [
        {
            \"region\": \"ON\",
            \"tel\": \"(519)452-4430\",
            \"category_labels\": [
                [
                    \"CommunityandGovernment\",
                    \"Education\",
                    \"CollegesandUniversities\"
                ]
            ],
            \"name\": \"FanshaweCollege\",
            \"longitude\": -81.200929,
            \"fax\": \"(519)452-4420\",
            \"website\": \"http: //www.fanshawec.ca\",
            \"hours\": {
                \"monday\": [
                    [
                        \"6: 00\",
                        \"17: 00\"
                    ]
                ],
                \"tuesday\": [
                    [
                        \"6: 00\",
                        \"17: 00\"
                    ]
                ],
                \"wednesday\": [
                    [
                        \"6: 00\",
                        \"17: 00\"
                    ]
                ],
                \"friday\": [
                    [
                        \"6: 00\",
                        \"13: 00\"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            \"neighborhood\": [
                \"HuronHeights\"
            ],
            \"postcode\": \"N5Y5R6\",
            \"category_ids\": [
                29
            ],
            \"country\": \"ca\",
            \"address\": \"1001FanshaweCollegeBlvd\",
            \"locality\": \"London\",
            \"hours_display\": \"Mon-Wed6: 00-17: 00;Fri6: 00-13: 00\",
            \"latitude\": 43.013919,
            \"factual_id\": \"fba3ee56-9947-424d-bba4-f6c955491fff\",
            \"$distance\": 219.42628
        }
    ],
    \"included_rows\": 1
}
}"
```

This is how I'm trying to interact with the JSON:

```
success: function (data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data.d);
        $.each(result, function (i, item) {
            console.log(result.latitude);
        });
    }
```

I am getting the json from an ajax call and have tried data.d and creating an object using JSON.parse and accessing it that way but I am still having issues drilling down to the actual data. I keep getting undefined errors.

How am I supposed to parse a JSON string that's like this?

Comment: You parse it with `JSON.parse()` or `$.parseJSON()`. What's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by trying `data.d`? The `data` property is an array, so you need to index it.

Comment: If you specify `dataType: 'json'` in your AJAX call, jQuery will automatically parse it for you. But I suspect your problem isn't with parsing the JSON, but with accessing the data properly in the resulting object. You need to explain which parts you're trying to access, and show your attempted code.

Comment: @Barmar see my edit, how would I iterate through to get the latitude and longitude for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$.each(result.response.data, function(i, item) {
    console.log(item.latitude);
});
```

From the JSON, you can see that the array of locations is nested:

```
"{
\"version\": 3,
\"status\": \"ok\",
\"response\": {
    \"data\": [
```

The first level is the `response` property, and within that is the `data` property.

And then in your loop, you were using `response.latitude` instead of `item.latitude`.